# Accessibility menu keeps appearing

Tags: accessibility, popup

On my Moto G4 the Accessibility settings menu keeps popping up, and I can't make it go away. The only thing that works temporarily is to put the phone on standby, then reopen and the phone works normally for about 30 secs before the menu pops up again. I've tried turning off the phone and it still keeps happening. Any ideas?

Comment: This is happening on a friend's Nexus 7 (on Android 6). I'm mystified.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my galaxy s7. I've uninstalled apps and reset all my setting back to default to see if that worked. The only time it stops is shortly after I turn my phone on in the morning for about a minute

Comment: Look at the list of accessibility services that look disabled in that menu. A rogue app could be trying to trick you into enabling its accessibility service.